# SSL Handshake Failure - no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication

Tags: java, spring, ssl, https, openshift

We have a legacy system deployed on WAS which I am trying to migrate to Openshift cloud. There is a service which runs fine on WAS but I am getting SSL Handshake Failure when I deploy on Openshift container.

I tried few fixes and now it works on test perfectly but not in PROD. Upon further analysis I found that I get the SSL handshake error only when I switch from Test DB to PROD DB (keeping the code base and JKS same). I did try SSL Debug and found that the below line when I am connected to PROD DB which doesn't appear when connected to Test DB.

> Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client
>   authentication

I have tried setting up Environment vairables using `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` . I also cross checked both the DBs for any difference in the properties but couldn't find any.

***CertificateRequest

```
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
```

**Cert Authorities:**

```
<Empty>

update handshake state: unknown[13]

upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]

upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)

upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]

upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)

upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]

upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]

upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]

upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]

pool-6-thread-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4

check handshake state: server_hello_done[14]

update handshake state: server_hello_done[14]

upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)

upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]

upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)

upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]

upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]

upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]

upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
```

**ServerHelloDone**

> Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client
>   authentication

**Certificate chain**

```
<Empty>

update handshake state: certificate[11]

upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]

upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)

upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]

upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]

upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]

upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
```

Comment: The test server is configured to request a client certificate and your client does not provide any. It might be that the prod server is differently configured and will not request such a certificate. It might be that the prod server will request a certificate but expect it to be signed by a different CA then what the test server wants. Unfortunately nothing is known about the configurations of prod and test server so these are only guesses based on the few information you've provided.

Comment: The thing is, the URL (Service) is the same, the certificate I am using is the same, the issue I face is only when I switch DB. So I was hoping if someone can suggest how can I configure the keystore and truststore in Java for jBoss 6.4

Comment: If the difference is when switching the DB's then the cause of the problem a difference in the DB's setup, not in the setup of your client.

Comment: Well I checked both the DBs but couldn't find any significant difference, hence I am thinking of setting the truststore and keystore in the java code which would then be independent of the DB

Comment: If you have different configurations on the client for connecting to the DB's then these differences might be the reason and you could try to align these configurations. But if you don't have different configurations on the client then the configuration of the databases itself must be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please check and make sure you are using the same password to secure the keystore and the private key. USing the same password should solve this